# setTimeout function is quicker than it should be

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, webstorm

I have the following function in selenium test and setTimeout function is always done about 25% faster than it should be. In this case want to wait 20 seconds and function is done after 15 seconds.

```
test.describe('basic login test',function(){
    this.timeout(timeout);
    // variables
    test.before(...);

    test.it.only('Test', function(done){
        testLoginPage.load().then(...)
        .then(...).then(...)
        .then(...).then(...)
        .then(function(){
            var first = "1st: " + new Date().getTime();
            console.log(first);    
            setTimeout(function(){
                driver.getTitle().then(function(title){
                    assert.equal(title, 'Tittle', 'Error.');
                });
                console.log(first);
                console.log("2nd: " + new Date().getTime());
                done();
            }, 20000);
       }).then(...)
    });
    test.after();
});
```

Output:

```
1st: 1457706590459
1st: 1457706590459
2nd: 1457706605462
```

Comment: seTimeout is not changed by selenium or webstorm ... make sure there is no other function that might be logging date and clearing the timeout.

Comment: Could you tell me why there are 2 output although there are 3 console.log in your code? Can you add an id for each console.log such as `console.log("1st: " + new Date().getTime());`

Comment: @Buaban edited and rafaelcastrocouto I'm pretty sure...

Comment: It cannot be. Could you try this: assign start time to a variable. Then while printing second time, print first time as well. This is just to verify, if no other function or callback is making this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Impossible, except for the following cases.

- Your code or library you are using, has a overridden customized `setTimeout` function and it is calling actual `setTimeout` function with lesser milliseconds.
- You are using a `JavaScript` runtime (very old), with a **VERY VERY CRITICAL** issue.
- Some other `function` is printing it in between (doesn't look like that from your code though)

Comment: Yes, that's impossible, you have been right. I am ashamed to say this but my fix was the restart of Windows OS :-/. Thanks for your time and sorry about that.